# SSMS Web Interface

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Does anyone know if there's a tool out there which allows you to run queries against a SQL Server database through a web browser (e.g. SSMS functionality available through the browser)?

I ask as we have a large support team who rely heavily on running database queries when investigating issues.  As our data center (where the DBs are hosted) is based remotely from our offices, and many of our support staff are working offshore over VPN it's helpful to allow them to access a client hosted at the data center.  One solution would be to host SSMS on a terminal server, but having a web front end would be more straight forward, should one exist.

Comment: For anyone following this post, myLittleAdmin looks like the better tool (very similar to SSMS), but SQL Web Admin's free.  As I don't have a budget for this SQL Web Admin won, but if anyone has cash to play with I'd recommend going the myLittleAdmin route.

Comment: Update: SqlPad takes the top spot.  This was created after this question was initially asked, but satisfies all the requirements and more (i.e. includes a SQL to Graph feature, which will be really useful for various bits of analysis work).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may like [sqlpad](https://github.com/rickbergfalk/sqlpad).

It's a Node.js web app for writing and running SQL queries and visualizing the results. Supports Postgres, MySQL, **SQL Server**, Crate and Vertica.

It has many contributors and it's being kept up-to-date.

## IIS / iisnode specifics

You may be using IIS with iisnode. That's working too. You only need to alter the port config in /lib/config.js line 12 to use `process.env.PORT`.

When you want to use Google Authentication. You need to have this in your web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
      <add key="GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID" value="..." />
      <add key="GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET" value="..." />
      <add key="PUBLIC_URL" value="https://example.com" />
      <add key="DISABLE_USERPASS_AUTH" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

*PS: The last key is optional for when you want to only allow google logins*

Comment: I'm currently looking on setting up on Apache2, where shall I add this keys?

Answer (score 6):

None from Microsoft but there are 3rd party tools available, such as myLittleAdmin.

Answer (score 4):

You are wanting something like [SQL Web Data Admin](http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/).

It does not provide all the features of SSMS but it does enough to be able to support/manage the sql server remotely.

There are other tools that are based of this project on codeplex that add additional functionality.